# SSAS process option : Data

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, business-intelligence

I am doing a SSAS project using SQL Server 2016 Standard version that contains partitions, and SSIS to create the processing logic, where dynamically it only processes the last partition.

I've read about the Process Option data, and it says the following:

> BOL: Process Data - load data into a table without rebuilding hierarchies or relationships or recalculating calculated columns and measures

My question is: if I add in my SSIS logic a Analysis Services Processing Task to process the measure groups with the option **Data**, is it the same of processing all my partitions ? Am I kinda doing the same process twice ?

Currently my processing logic is the following:

1. Process Dimensions: Default
2. Process Dimensions: Update
3. Process Measure Group: Data
4. Process Partition(Last based on date): Full
5. Process all objects: Index

I'm not that expert in SSAS, so any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would do the data part twice. No need to process data if you are going for a Process Update / Full of the measure group later on.